# Best practice react, redux, multiple async calls

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, reactjs, redux

I have a react contain that makes an ajax request via `@asynConnect`.  Once that data comes back from the server, this component's render method will conditionally render several components.  Some of these components have their own data that is required to render their content.  What is the best way to fetch the data for each child component?  Do I use `componentWillMount`?  Should my parent container dispatch another action that when received will make the subsequent ajax calls?  Should I use some type of middleware (`redux-thunk`)?  I've read multiple posts and comments on this topic and still not sure if I've come across a "best practice".  FWIW I'm using this project: https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example

Comment: Jumping into redux with a boilerplate project is not encouraged; it confuses rather than clarifies. That said, the Redux documentation contains a fantastic guide on how to approach async actions: http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html